# Text in a UIButton doesn't appear when set programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a standard `UIButton` which I've connected as an outlet to a view controller.

Within the VC if I have this:

```
self.pulldownButton.hidden = NO;
[self.pulldownButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Some text", @"some key")
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then the button appears but it's empty.

Comment: That is correct.  Is the button added programatically or through IB?

Comment: Through IB, and the connections inspector is showing it is connected to the pulldownButton property.

Comment: @Mungbeans I have updated my answer check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in your code. It is fine. I suppose you have added button through IB and you have not connected its outlet. Thats why no change reflects. So connect outlet.

Edit: Other case may be you have set an image in foreground rather then background. So if you have set an image in button in foreground then set it to background.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No its outlet is connected, I can see the connection in the connections inspector.

Comment: Have you set image in UIButton?

Comment: If you have set image in button then set it in background if already not set in background.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 do this to check if the issue is with background:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
self.pulldownButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
self.pulldownButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

## 2 Log to check if the frame and super view are proper:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.pulldownButton.superview.rect));
    NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(self.pulldownButton.rect));
}
```